# Can I add a field to the Membership table in the aspnet.mdf

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I would like to add just one extra field to Membership table in the aspnet.mdf.

I want to add an IMEI field to identify phones that access the database,  I only want to use the AccountController and AccountModel and I don’t want to create a custom membership provider. Just one extra field in the database.

Can this be done?

Comment: check this question and aswer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3823080/559144

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.net membership add custom column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823037/asp-net-membership-add-custom-column)